# ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success") gives linking error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, build-error

I get the below error while building my swift project post linking `ProgressHUD` to my swift code.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ProgressHUD", referenced from:
>
> objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I did an `#import "ProgressHUD.h"` in bridging file and then went to my view controller and tried adding

`ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")` - > Build fails post this line

Comment: are you tried in simulator as well as are you used the pods or else

Comment: it's SVProgressHUD not ProgressHUD,
SVProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")

Comment: Senthil is referring to this -> https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as a general problem with Xcode.

(Though if you could have mentioned the version of xcode you're using it would have been easy for the community.)

**Anyways try below fixes Hope they will work :**

- Open preferences Goto - > Locations and click on the gray circle arrow after clicking on open DerivedData folder -> select all -> right click -> move to trash. [Restart your mac].

[image]

- Click on your project -> Goto General Tab -> scroll to bottom to Linked Frameworks and library -> click on " + " Now from the list shown type your Framework in search bar and click on **Add**.

[image]

Now Goto **Build Phases** tab on the right side in the same row of **General** - > Do the same by searching and adding your Framework

[image]
Now,

- Clean your project -> *shift + command + k*
- Also, Now hit the keys : *command + b* [to build the proj.]

Hope it'll work for you.
Still you face any problem put a comment down, I'll Reply ASAP.!

**Lastly**  : [ Mine is *Xcode-9* too ]

- Try This : Goto the build Settings Search for Bridging header [Simply type bridg..] it'll show you, now add the Path of your module appending your bridging header file name. Simply double click on the value for the key : Objective-C Bridging Header on the right side. it'll show a Pop-Up add the below line into that it'll do the rest.

> ```
> $(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift-Bridging-Header.h
> ```

[image]

I hope Now it'll do the job. =)

Comment: It did not work. My Xcode version is 9.0 (9A235). I am not able to complete the below step: Click on your project -> Goto General Tab -> scroll to bottom to Linked Frameworks and library -> click on " + " Now from the list shown type your Framework in search bar and click on Add. When i type progress, nothing shows up

Answer (score 1):

To use ProgressHUD in Xcode 10, I had to add the supporting files (ProgressHUD.h, ProgressHUD.m, [AppName]-Bridging-Header.h) to the 'Compile Sources' area, located at Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. The ProgressHUD.bundle is located in the 'Copy Bundle Resources'.